# Should social media links open in a new tab or window?

Tags: usability, design-patterns, social-media, user-expectation

Is it advisable that social media links (facebook, twitter, etc) will open in a new tab? Does it depends on the number of social media links?, What if there were only 3 social media links?, should I go for open those links in new tabs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a subject that has being discussed many times and the answer depends on your perspective. The most common consensus is to open anything that is not your website in a new tab or window.

If you want to read about the reasons for that, or the opposite option, you can check [the answer I  wrote](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/53624/20789) on the question [When (if ever) should links be opened in a new window?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/31579/when-if-ever-should-links-be-opened-in-a-new-window/). That way you cane make a more educated decision after reading references, opinions of experts and many thoughts of people regarding the experts perspective.