# Any research about "few markets" that expect external links to be opened in new windows/tabs?

Tags: website-design, research, hyperlinks, internationalisation

[Google AdSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdSense), an advertisement service, documents in "[Opening the ads in a new window](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354740?hl=en)":

> Generally, it is our policy to not allow Google ads to open in a new window. However, in a few markets, including China, we've found that opening ads in a new window better aligns with expected internet behavior and provides a more consistent, intuitive user experience.

Is there any published research about the culture/country difference regarding opening links in new windows/tabs?

Should we really open external links in new windows/tabs by default for users from these "few markets"? Do these users expect *all* external links to be opened in new windows/tabs or would an icon/notice still be advisable?

I couldn’t find anything mentioned in the questions:

- [Is there ever a good reason to force opening a new browser window?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/13727/17023)
- [Opening website external links in new window -- published usability tests](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/19892/17023)
- [When (if ever) should links be opened in a new window?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/31579/17023)

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't find any research, so I have conducted my own. I've looked at the top 5 websites in China and in the United States, according to Alexa.

For the top websites in China:

```
Site        | # Links | # New Window | % New Window
baidu.com   | 26      | 3            | 11.5%
qq.com      | 1026    | 985          | 96.0%
taobao.com  | 398     | 335          | 84.2%
sina.com.cn | 2047    | 1849         | 90.3%
hao123.com  | 810     | 791          | 97.7%
              4307      3963           92.0%
```

So about 92% of all links on Chinese websites open in a new window.

For the United States:

```
Site          | # Links | # New Window | % New Window
google.com    | 48      | 4            | 8.3%
youtube.com   | 329     | 5            | 1.5%
yahoo.com     | 211     | 6            | 2.8%
amazon.com    | 308     | 1            | 0.3%
wikipedia.org | 313     | 0            | 0.0%
                1209      16             1.3%
```

So about 1.3% of all links on United States websites open in a new window.

So it is obvious that there are two different sets of expectations amongst these groups of users, and opening in a new window might well be the expected behaviour for Chinese users.

Comment: Maybe it's semantics, but I wonder if it's really a cultural difference or if it's merely a technology implementation difference (ie, did chinese web browsers initially always open links in new windows?)